# Detecting if a button is pressed before an amount of time has passed

Tags: android

I am currently working on an android app for a study that requires participants to press a button before a certain amount of time has passed. If they do not press the button before time is up, the app should move onto the next trial. All of the answers about waiting an amount of time while being able to be interrupted involve threads, which I do not have I high degree of experience with. This is what I have at the moment:

```
            final Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        end = time + timeAllowed;

        //button click listeners
        Log.d("Here", "ClickListener");
        low.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                response = 0;
                end = (long)0;
                Log.d("Clicked", "Clicked!");
            }
        });
        high.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                response = 1;
                end = (long)0;
            }
        });
        //actually waiting
        //This is a really stupid hack
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end)
        {}//nothing happens yet
        //timeAllowed has passed
        responseTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
```

This is all contained within a for loop of 48 trials. For some reason, my onClickListeners do not properly create until the for-loop is done executing, even when I place them above the beginning of the for loop. In addition, the code fails to mark which button should be pressed until after the loop (done by setting the button.setText above the shown code segment). What might I be doing wrong?

To be completely clear, I want to wait for either a button press or time to expire before continuing.

Cory's response is what I currently have implemented.

I really need a response to this. Thanks
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record the time when the button is first shown with `System.currentTimeMillis()` and then use the same method to get the time with the button is clicked. The difference with be how long it took them.

To record a click not happening within a certain amount of time you could use this , which would be put in your onResume with the recording of the start time.

```
Handler handlerTimer = new Handler();

handlerTimer.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
      // do something             
  }}, 20000);
```

Comment: That seems quite a bit simpler than what I was trying to do, but how will I know when the time has elapsed to move on if the button hasn't been pressed?

Comment: You could set a handler to with a delayed post. Editing post to show.